# cant send email headers

Tags: php

I am unable to send email address carried from email box in html form.
when i fill up the form email box with someone@yahoo.com the email is send to the mailbox
but when i fill the form email box with someon@gmail.com the email script works but the email doesn't come in the mailbox or the spam folder.

```
-----*This is the html code*-------

<input type="email" name="email" id="email" size="70" /></td>

-----*-------------

$email_from = "$mail";
$email_to = "someone@gmail.com"; 
$email_message ="test message";


$email_subject = "Registration form "; // email subject line

$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1'."\r\n";
$headers .= 'From:'.$mail;
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
```

Comment: You should use a library like [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) or (my personal preference) [SwiftMailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) for sending email. Sending email from PHP is a solved problem, but using `mail()` directly is pretty much the worst possible solution.

Comment: You've apparently disabled error reporting because `$mail` pops up from nowhere. Additionally, you don't even test `mail()`'s return value.